# basic grid plugin for jquery

Tags: jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I am looking for a very simple data grid plugin for jquery that will allow me to do the following

- populate it
- order columns a->z and z->a
- add rows on the client

I am using asp.net mvc on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqGrid is probably the best grid plugin out there, it should do all you need above, and provide ample room for growth down the road if needed.

http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Comment: it seems to be mostly server driven. I have done some reading on it and it appears that every click generates a server action.....i am still reading, but in the examples I don't see any JS code, it's all Controller code.

Comment: Take a look at the arraydata example under the loading data tab
http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: you beat me! I was looking at the server side component. Duh.:)

Comment: About as easy as it gets to load data and bind it to a grid :)

Answer (score 1):

DataTables is pretty straightforward and easily configurable:

http://datatables.net/

Their examples page lists a number of ready to go implementations.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working with jquery.tablesorter.  API is pretty clear; you can override the sorting function to provide custom sorting.  In this example, notice that i have a grouping header as well, for which I can disable sorting.

```
<div style="width: 1024px; overflow: scroll">

<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Skill</th>
            <th colspan="2">Resource</th>
            <th colspan="2">Project</th>
            <th>Role</th>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Skill</th>
            <th>Complexity</th>
            <th>Bill</th>
            <th>Joe</th>
            <th>Project 1</th>
            <th>Project 2</th>
            <th>Role 1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>.Net</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>UX</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>WCF</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
 (function ($) {

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#myTable").tablesorter({

                headers: {
                    0: { sorter: false },
                    1: { sorter: false },
                    2: { sorter: false },
                    3: { sorter: false }

                }
            });



        });

    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

jsGrid is a really lightweight and customizable jQuery grid plugin http://js-grid.com/